# Why we need more look up in a hash table key match?

Tags: java, hash, hashtable

from java.util.Hashtable:

```
    public synchronized boolean containsKey(Object key) {
    Entry tab[] = table;
    int hash = key.hashCode();
    int index = (hash & 0x7FFFFFFF) % tab.length;
    for (Entry<K,V> e = tab[index] ; e != null ; e = e.next) {
        if ((e.hash == hash) && e.key.equals(key)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

we have computed the index form the key's hashcode, so why we need **e.next** and continue lookup?

Answer (score 3):

We can have multiple (different) objects with the same hash.

For example: names in phone book under the letter A.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table

Answer (score 2):

There may be several elements with **different keys, but the same hash**.

This is the very idea of a Hashmap. Once you have found the hash of your key, you need to iterate on all elements with that hash to find the one with the right key.